# Web Deploy from local project to IIS 7 not working - won't display site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, iis-7, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to publish a local web project (this is a basic MVC template project, nothing special) in 2013 Visual Studio Express to an IIS file. It's building and publishing the files to where I want them to go - but when it opens the link to the project in IIS to view in a browser, I'm just getting the "This page can't be displayed" without any other hint as to why, or a specific error msg.

I'm pretty sure its something in IIS that's dodgy, since I'm not getting any errors from VS when I publish and its pushing the files from my local folder to the IIS folder.

This is what I've done so far in IIS:

- installed the Wed Deploy extension and added the proper publishing permissions
- added the web site to the "Sites" folder.
- filled in the site name, used ASP.NEt v4.0 as the application pool.
- put in the physical path to the folder
- entered the host name: www.webtest.companyname.com

Then I went back to VS and set the Web Deploy settings. I created a new profile, used the "Web Deploy" publish method and I got all the information in, validated the connection and then hit publish. The build succeeded and I didn't get any errors. I went back to IIS and saw that the files had been published but when you click the link under the:

"Browse Web site" link which reads: www.webtest.companyname.com on *:80(http)

All I get is the error: This Page Can't be displayed.

Any thoughts or ideas on why I can't get this project to work in IIS 7?